# Difference between sum and count in aggregate case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

I have a query below as:

```
    SELECT 
       d.name, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN e.salary > 100000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        / COUNT(DISTINCT e.id)
        AS pct_above_100k,
      COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) AS c
FROM employees e JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.id
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

I am using sum here, but would there be any difference if I was using count?

I know count counts the number of times a value exists and sum adds up the actual values, but here since my condition is if the salary is > 100000 it would look at that as 1 anyway right?

Thanks!

Comment: Correct. `Count` would get the same result.

Comment: I dont agree, Count will still count the row whether its value evaluate to 0 or 1 while sum will sum i.e. if value if condition is true three times then it will return 3 while count will return number of rows regardless condition is true or false.

Comment: The `sum` is the same as `count(*) filter (where e.salary > 10000) ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We count conditionally with a filter clause:

```
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE e.salary > 100000)
```

Some other dBMS don't support the filter clause. Here we use workarounds by evaluating the expression ourselves with `CASE WHEN` and either use `COUNT` or `SUM` to add the matches up. Here are some ways to do this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN e.salary > 100000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
COUNT(CASE WHEN e.salary > 100000 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
COUNT(CASE WHEN e.salary > 100000 THEN 1 END)
COUNT(CASE WHEN e.salary > 100000 THEN 'count this' END)
```

As PostgreSQL does support the filter clause you should use `COUNT(*) FILTER (...)`.

Comment: This approach should also work in Trino.

Answer (score 2):

If you just replaced `sum` with `count`, you would get a different result, since 0 counts as much as 1.

The most elegant way to write this is a `FILTER` clause, as others have mentioned, but you could also do this:

```
count(CASE WHEN e.salary > 100000 THEN 0 END)
```

This would work because NULL values are ignored by (most) aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, employees are not in multiple departments, so the `count(distinct)` is unnecessary.

That means that the code can be more simply written as:

```
  AVG(CASE WHEN e.salary > 100000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pct_above_100k,
```

Or:

```
  AVG( (e.salary > 100000)::int ) AS pct_above_100k,
```

These will be more efficient than the alternatives because `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is usually a bit more expensive than other aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify it to this:
SUM(e.salary > 100000)
Although I'm not sure why this works.

whereas if you used COUNT you have to use WHERE for the condition.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).